# Popover size with UINavigationController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I have created an iPad app containing a popover view embedded in a navigation controller. I like using Storyboard as much as possible, and setting the `"Use Explicit Size"` in Xcode give me the correct size of my popover on the iPad. But it does not resize the `UINavigationController` view and its embedded `UIViewControllers` when viewing the storyboard in Xcode.

This is quite annoying as the size of my view in Xcode does not correspond to the actual size of the popover.

So, my problem is not setting the correct size of the popover (i also know i can do that with code), but I want the views in storyboard to show the actual size of my views.

What is the correct way to create viewControllers embedded in a navigation controller using storyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the views embedded in the navigation controller, you can change their size in the storyboard by doing the following:

1. Select the View Controller.
2. Go to the Attributes Inspector under Simulated Metrics and select Size: Freeform.
3. Select the View Controller's view.
4. Go to the Size Inspector and change the width and height.

After that, the view should be sized correctly in the storyboard.

Unfortunately I do not know how to change the size of the navigation controller.

Comment: Thank you! The solution feels a bit as a work around for me, as I think the views should update according to the "Use Explicit Size". But, thank you again. I'll mark your answer as accepted if nothing better comes up in the very near future.

Comment: if you uncheck "Use explicit size" on the view controller, the view controller in storyboard will adjust its size to the size of your view inside your view controller.