# Change the size if a Popover when using Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I would like to change to size of a Popover when using it as a segue in `Interface Builder`.

I had already set the size of my ViewController to an explicit value, but the popover has still the `standard size`

[image: Specific size]

I'll found this:

[Popover size with UINavigationController in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024170/popover-size-with-uinavigationcontroller-in-storyboard)

But this is not working for me. Is this not possible with Storyboard Editor? Otherwise i will need to call it manually on BarButtonItem click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app runs on iOS version < 7, use **contentSizeForViewInPopover**:

```
// Inside your view controller
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{
    return CGSizeMake(450, 250);
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated.  Use `preferredContentSize`, or from the popover use `setContentSize:`

Comment: Thanks. But how can i use this? There is no method "contentSizeForViewInPopover" in my UIPopoverControllerDelegate. I Know i can use setContentSize if i call it manually, but is there a way to set this to my Popover in the IB?

Comment: @derdida - You'd add this to the view controller being presented in the popover.  With that said, it is deprecated so other solutions are probably better.

Comment: Thanks. self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 250) in my PopoverViewController works fine!